# web3py - get transaction result

Tags: transactions, web3.py, uniswap

I'm trying to parse the following UniswapV3 transaction in Python using web3:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x086d2ae22b7ba31245c842060f7e94b61b922795ca3b3fbff326ba63db00060a

Etherscan shows as Transaction action `'Swap 0.549 Ether For 64.163408010311978832 CARDS On Uniswap V3'`

I'm able to parse the input data and retrieve the contract function input parameters using `contract.decode_function_input`:

| Name | Type | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| params.amountIn | uint256 | 549000000000000000 |
| params.amountOutMinimum | uint256 | 63844187074937292370 |

However I don't see how I can retrieve the output of the contract function which is shown in the transaction action field in Etherscan (64.163408010311978832 CARDS), i.e. the result of the function `function exactInputSingle(ExactInputSingleParams calldata params) external payable returns (uint256 amountOut);` (coming from the Uniswap V3 code functions: https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564#code).

How can I retrieve it ?

Thanks a lot for your help